# Get varnish to proxy and not redirect

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I want to use Varnish as a "smart" proxy and it almost works. The idea is that some requests should be passed through Varnish, hit the backend and return, all other requests should return a "synt" message that the specific response contains no result.

This works apart from the fact that Varnish returns a 301 redirect to the backend instead of just the response from the actual backend.

Backend and Cache are not located on the same host (or not even on the same network in this case).

Backend is ALSO running a separate Varnish instance and this request is always passed through that.

```
// VCL.SHOW 0 1820 input
#
# This is an example VCL file for Varnish.
#
# It does not do anything by default, delegating control to the
# builtin VCL. The builtin VCL is called when there is no explicit
# return statement.
#
# See the VCL chapters in the Users Guide at https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/
# and http://varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExamples for more examples.

# Marker to tell the VCL compiler that this VCL has been adapted to the
# new 4.0 format.
vcl 4.0;

### Here starts my part of the VCL    

# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
    .host = "myhost.mydomain";
    .port = "80";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    # Happens before we check if we have this in cache already.
    #
    # Typically you clean up the request here, removing cookies you don't need,
    # rewriting the request, etc.

    if (req.url ~ "^\/cgi-bin\/wspd_cgi\.sh/apiFlightSearch.p\?from=ARN&to=AOK&date=2017-05-20&homedate=2017-05-27")
    {
       return (hash);
    }

    return (synth(750));
}

sub vcl_synth {
    if (resp.status == 750) {
        # Set a status the client will understand
        set resp.status = 200;
        # Create our synthetic response
        set resp.http.content-type = "text/xml";
        synthetic("<flights xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'><status><status>No flights</status></status></flights>");
        return(deliver);
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Happens after we have read the response headers from the backend.
    #
    # Here you clean the response headers, removing silly Set-Cookie headers
    # and other mistakes your backend does.

    set beresp.ttl = 10 s;
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Happens when we have all the pieces we need, and are about to send the
    # response to the client.
    #
    # You can do accounting or modifying the final object here.
}

### Here ends my part of the VCL. The rest I guess is built in.

// VCL.SHOW 1 5479 Builtin
/*-
 * Copyright (c) 2006 Verdens Gang AS
 * Copyright (c) 2006-2014 Varnish Software AS
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * Author: Poul-Henning Kamp <phk@phk.freebsd.dk>
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE AUTHOR AND CONTRIBUTORS ``AS IS'' AND
 * ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
 * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
 * ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL AUTHOR OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
 * FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
 * DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS
 * OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION)
 * HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
 * LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY
 * OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF
 * SUCH DAMAGE.
 *

 *
 * The built-in (previously called default) VCL code.
 *
 * NB! You do NOT need to copy & paste all of these functions into your
 * own vcl code, if you do not provide a definition of one of these
 * functions, the compiler will automatically fall back to the default
 * code from this file.
 *
 * This code will be prefixed with a backend declaration built from the
 * -b argument.
 */

vcl 4.0;

#######################################################################
# Client side

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.method == "PRI") {
        /* We do not support SPDY or HTTP/2.0 */
        return (synth(405));
    }
    if (req.method != "GET" &&
      req.method != "HEAD" &&
      req.method != "PUT" &&
      req.method != "POST" &&
      req.method != "TRACE" &&
      req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
      req.method != "DELETE") {
        /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
        return (pipe);
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        /* We only deal with GET and HEAD by default */
        return (pass);
    }
    if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
        /* Not cacheable by default */
        return (pass);
    }
    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_pipe {
    # By default Connection: close is set on all piped requests, to stop
    # connection reuse from sending future requests directly to the
    # (potentially) wrong backend. If you do want this to happen, you can undo
    # it here.
    # unset bereq.http.connection;
    return (pipe);
}

sub vcl_pass {
    return (fetch);
}

sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.url);
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }
    return (lookup);
}

sub vcl_purge {
    return (synth(200, "Purged"));
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
        // A pure unadultered hit, deliver it
        return (deliver);
    }
    if (obj.ttl + obj.grace > 0s) {
        // Object is in grace, deliver it
        // Automatically triggers a background fetch
        return (deliver);
    }
    // fetch & deliver once we get the result
    return (fetch);
}

sub vcl_miss {
    return (fetch);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    return (deliver);
}

/*
 * We can come here "invisibly" with the following errors: 413, 417 & 503
 */
sub vcl_synth {
    set resp.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    set resp.http.Retry-After = "5";
    synthetic( {"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>"} + resp.status + " " + resp.reason + {"</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Error "} + resp.status + " " + resp.reason + {"</h1>
    <p>"} + resp.reason + {"</p>
    <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>
    <p>XID: "} + req.xid + {"</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Varnish cache server</p>
  </body>
</html>
"} );
    return (deliver);
}

#######################################################################
# Backend Fetch

sub vcl_backend_fetch {
    return (fetch);
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
      beresp.http.Set-Cookie ||
      beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
      (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&
        beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store|private") ||
      beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
        /*
        * Mark as "Hit-For-Pass" for the next 2 minutes
        */
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    }
    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_backend_error {
    set beresp.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    set beresp.http.Retry-After = "5";
    synthetic( {"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>"} + beresp.status + " " + beresp.reason + {"</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Error "} + beresp.status + " " + beresp.reason + {"</h1>
    <p>"} + beresp.reason + {"</p>
    <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>
    <p>XID: "} + bereq.xid + {"</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Varnish cache server</p>
  </body>
</html>
"} );
    return (deliver);
}

#######################################################################
# Housekeeping

sub vcl_init {
    return (ok);
}

sub vcl_fini {
    return (ok);
}
```

Output from curl:

```
$ curl "thisandthatip.compute.amazonaws.com/cgi-bin/wspd_cgi.sh/apiFlightSearch.p?from=ARN&to=AOK&date=2017-05-20&homedate=2017-05-27&adults=2&triptype=return&children=0&infants=0" -i
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 15 Mar 2017 07:14:11 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
Location: http://myserver.mydomain/cgi-bin/wspd_cgi.sh/apiFlightSearch.p?from=ARN&to=AOK&date=2017-05-20&homedate=2017-05-27&adults=2&triptype=return&children=0&infants=0
Content-Length: 514
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
X-Varnish: 529144137
Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
X-Varnish: 98309 11
Age: 2
Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
Connection: keep-alive

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://myserver.mydomain/cgi-bin/wspd_cgi.sh/apiFlightSearch.p?from=ARN&amp;to=AOK&amp;date=2017-05-20&amp;homedate=2017-05-27&amp;adults=2&amp;triptype=return&amp;children=0&amp;infants=0">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at thisandthatip.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Backend apache access log

```
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2017:08:09:49 +0100] "GET /cgi-bin/wspd_cgi.sh/apiFlightSearch.p?from=arn&to=aok&date=2017-05-20&homedate=2017-05-27&adults=2&triptype=return&children=0&infants=0 HTTP/1.1" 200 994 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
```

Sending the request from the AWS instance to the backend renders no 301 redirection:

```
$ curl "myserver.mydomain/cgi-bin/wspd_cgi.sh/apiFlightSearch.p?from=arn&to=aok&date=2017-05-20&homedate=2017-05-27&adults=2&triptype=return&children=0&infants=0" -i
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 15 Mar 2017 08:54:14 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
Cache-Control: max-age=1
Expires: Wed, 15 Mar 2017 08:54:15 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml
X-Varnish: 527559784
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Ranges: bytes

... Response body here ...
```

Complete varnishlog output of a single request

```
*   << BeReq    >> 98314
-   Begin          bereq 98313 fetch
-   Timestamp      Start: 1489568144.701450 0.000000 0.000000
-   BereqMethod    GET
-   BereqURL       /cgi-bin/wspd_cgi.sh/apiFlightSearch.p?from=ARN&to=AOK&date=2017-05-20&homedate=2017-05-27&adults=2&triptype=return&children=0&infants=0
-   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
-   BereqHeader    Host: thisandthatip.compute.amazonaws.com
-   BereqHeader    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
-   BereqHeader    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
-   BereqHeader    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: ip.ip.ip.ip
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 98314
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   BackendClose   17 default(ip.ip.ip.ip,,80) toolate
-   BackendOpen    17 default(ip.ip.ip.ip,,80) 172.31.31.195 42868
-   Backend        17 default default(ip.ip.ip.ip,,80)
-   Timestamp      Bereq: 1489568144.730329 0.028878 0.028878
-   Timestamp      Beresp: 1489568144.759773 0.058322 0.029444
-   BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
-   BerespStatus   301
-   BerespReason   Moved Permanently
-   BerespHeader   Date: Wed, 15 Mar 2017 08:55:44 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
-   BerespHeader   Location: http://myserver.mydomain/cgi-bin/wspd_cgi.sh/apiFlightSearch.p?from=ARN&to=AOK&date=2017-05-20&homedate=2017-05-27&adults=2&triptype=return&children=0&infants=0
-   BerespHeader   Content-Length: 514
-   BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
-   BerespHeader   X-Varnish: 526644873
-   BerespHeader   Age: 0
-   BerespHeader   Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
-   BerespHeader   Connection: keep-alive
-   TTL            RFC 120 -1 -1 1489568145 1489568145 1489568144 0 0
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
-   TTL            VCL 10 10 0 1489568145
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Storage        malloc s0
-   ObjProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ObjStatus      301
-   ObjReason      Moved Permanently
-   ObjHeader      Date: Wed, 15 Mar 2017 08:55:44 GMT
-   ObjHeader      Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
-   ObjHeader      Location: http://myserver.mydomain/cgi-bin/wspd_cgi.sh/apiFlightSearch.p?from=ARN&to=AOK&date=2017-05-20&homedate=2017-05-27&adults=2&triptype=return&children=0&infants=0
-   ObjHeader      Content-Length: 514
-   ObjHeader      Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
-   ObjHeader      X-Varnish: 526644873
-   ObjHeader      Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
-   Fetch_Body     3 length stream
-   BackendReuse   17 default(ip.ip.ip.ip,,80)
-   Timestamp      BerespBody: 1489568144.759849 0.058398 0.000076
-   Length         514
-   BereqAcct      578 0 578 415 514 929
-   End

*   << Request  >> 98313
-   Begin          req 98312 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1489568144.701372 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1489568144.701372 0.000000 0.000000
-   ReqStart       ip.ip.ip.ip 63485
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /cgi-bin/wspd_cgi.sh/apiFlightSearch.p?from=ARN&to=AOK&date=2017-05-20&homedate=2017-05-27&adults=2&triptype=return&children=0&infants=0
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ReqHeader      Host: thisandthatip.compute.amazonaws.com
-   ReqHeader      Connection: keep-alive
-   ReqHeader      Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
-   ReqHeader      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: ip.ip.ip.ip
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   VCL_return     hash
-   ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   Debug          "XXXX MISS"
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 98314 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1489568144.759883 0.058511 0.058511
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     301
-   RespReason     Moved Permanently
-   RespHeader     Date: Wed, 15 Mar 2017 08:55:44 GMT
-   RespHeader     Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
-   RespHeader     Location: http://myserver.mydomain/cgi-bin/wspd_cgi.sh/apiFlightSearch.p?from=ARN&to=AOK&date=2017-05-20&homedate=2017-05-27&adults=2&triptype=return&children=0&infants=0
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 514
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 526644873
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 98313
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1489568144.759907 0.058535 0.000024
-   Debug          "RES_MODE 2"
-   RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1489568144.759933 0.058561 0.000026
-   Debug          "XXX REF 2"
-   ReqAcct        566 0 566 454 514 968
-   End
```

Varnish 4.0.4 running on AWS Amazon Linux.

Comment: that's very strange. Are you sure that it is not your backend that returns a 301? Can you share the output of varnishlog and your whole vcl conf, including the default vcl (varnishadm then vcl.show -v)

Comment: @BenjaminBaumann Added complete vcl as well as curl output and apache logs

Comment: I added an answer. If that does not solve your issue, the output of varnishlog will be very useful to understand the request track.

Answer (score 1):

The 301 redirect is not done by your varnish. It is done by an apache server probably your backend. It can be seen by the `X-Server` header in your curl.

What varnish does is proxify the request and forward it to the backend you declare `myhost.mydomain`. In fact Varnish will resolve the dns at startup and forward the request to the ip it got.

I see two things to check here :

1. ban your request from your varnish cache (it may result in a 301 at some time during your test and still be cached, that does not serm to be the case but better start from fresh cache)
2. Make a curl to your backend to see if you get a 301 or a 200.

If that does not work I would restart your varnish service to refresh the dns resolution.

Comment: Yes, it's clear that the redirect happens on the backend. Tried to run curl from the aws instance and got no 301. Added logs to question.

Comment: To clarify: curling from aws to backend directly = no 301. curl to aws from backend (or from aws instance itself) or accessing via browser = 301.

Comment: The host-header was the problem. The backend was hit with a host header matching the aws instance. Overriding it to match the backend solved the problem. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

The Host header entry sent to the backend matched that of the AWS instance. That triggered a redirect in the backend, not in the Varnish cache.

Overriding the http.resp.host value in Varnish solved the problem:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    # Happens before we check if we have this in cache already.
    #
    # Typically you clean up the request here, removing cookies you don't need,
    # rewriting the request, etc.

    # Set req.http.host (Host header) to www.airtours.se otherwise a redirect will be triggered
    set req.http.host = "myserver.mydomain";

    ... More setting goes here

}
```